# Mocha JS: grep not matching any tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

Mocha can't seem to match any patterns for some reason.

```
mocha -g MyClass
```

displays `0 passings (0ms)`, when I actually have several tests that can be run and passed if I run a single test script.

```
mocha test/my/test.js
```

yields `4 passing (10ms)`.

In `test.js`, I have

```
describe ('MyClass', function () {
    describe ('someMethod()', function () {
        it ('Should be...', function () {
            ....
        })
        ...
    })
})
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Using mocha 3.5.0.

Comment: worked fine for me with mocha 3.5.0

Comment: @john_omalley I'm using the same version. What exactly is your CLI command for using the grep option for that `test.js` above?

Comment: I just ran mocha -g FooBar for a spec with `describe('FooBar', () => ...`

Answer (score 5):

When you do `mocha test/my/test.js` Mocha has no trouble finding the test because you give a full path to the file. When you do `mocha -g MyClass`, Mocha has to find the file by itself. It looks in `test`, and your test file is located under it. So far so good, but by default Mocha won't go into subdirectories of `test`. So you have to do `mocha -g MyClass --recursive`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of Mocha apparently not finding specific tests that you're telling it to run with the `--grep` or `-g` option is if there are one or more other tests in your files that are defined with `.only( ... )`.

If Mocha sees any such `.only` tests, it won't run any other tests, even if your `--grep` argument doesn't include the `.only` test(s).

See: https://mochajs.org/#exclusive-tests